# Is there a class/struct in std that compares strings case insensitively and can be used as the Compare template in std::map?

Tags: c++, stl, std

To create a `std::map` with case insensitive `string` key, we can define a `struct CaseInsensitiveCompare`, and pass it as the `Compare` template when defining the `map`.

```
template<class T>
struct CaseInsensitiveCompare
{
    bool operator() (const T& l, const T& r) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(l.begin(), l.end(), r.begin(), r.end(), [](auto l, auto r) { return std::tolower(l, std::locale()) < std::tolower(r, std::locale()); });
    }
};

std::map<std::string, int, CaseInsensitiveCompare<std::string>> caseInsensitiveMap;
```

However, we need to define a `struct CaseInsensitiveCompare` whenever we need a case insensitive map. Is there anything in `std` that is equivalent to `struct CaseInsensitiveCompare`? Or is there any other way to define a case insensitive map without an additional struct?

Comment: The short answer is: nope. Useful and convenient locale support in C++ has been a pain point for a long time.

Comment: Case insensitivity is hard, because it all depends on the encoding.  Insensitive EBCDIC Code Page 37 will be entirely different than insensitive ISO 8859-1 which will be different than CCSID 1276 (Adobe PostScript Standard Encoding) which will be different than Unicode.  Support for locales and encodings is not one of C++ strengths.

Comment: Having a custom [`char_trait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) might be an alternative, see http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/029.htm